# Create sql logic to select specific row or group of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, rows

I'm trying to create a query from the sample data, and some logic that covers the results showing below (1-4). The field "Sufficient Qty" includes Y/N logic for the "Container_Qty - Required_Qty" calculation. The "Select Logic" column has the final results I'm looking for. It should only display the Container No(s) that have sufficient quantity (for a component) to fulfill the Required Quantity. Appreciate any suggestions. Thank you

```
CREATE TABLE #CONTAINER
(
  Job_No VARCHAR(25),
  Component_Key INT,
  Component_Name VARCHAR(125),
  Add_Date DATE,
  Container_No VARCHAR(25),
  Container_Qty DECIMAL(18,0) ,
  Required_Qty DECIMAL(18,0),
  Sufficient_QTY VARCHAR(2),
  Select_Logic VARCHAR(12));

INSERT #CONTAINER
VALUES
-- 1-Unique component with enough quantity.
 ('1266',   2947990 ,'Blister 6 Pack','6/14/2017' ,'S043', 20432,17280,'Y','Pick'),
 -- There are two containers for this component and both have enough quantity; pick the oldest one based on the "Container Add Date"
 ('1266',1887044,'Steel Cutters','7/14/2017 ,'S045',1374070,103680,'Y','Pick'),
 ('1266',1887044,'Steel Cutters','8/23/2017','S049',804324,103680,'Y','Do Not Pick'),
 -- 2-There are several containers for the same component; similar to data above.
 ('1266',2947990,'Blister Oral-B','7/30/2017','S046',43180,17280,'Y','Pick'),
 ( '1266',2947991,'Blister Oral-B','7/31/2017' ,'S047',44800,17280,'Y', 'Do Not Pick'),
 ( '1266',2947991,'Blister Oral-B,'8/2/2017','S048',33600,17280, 'Y','Do Not Pick'),
 ('1266',2947991,'Blister Oral-B,'8/4/2017','S051',17187,17280,'N','Do Not Pick'),    
( '1266',2947991,'Blister Oral-B','8/4/2017','S055',23600,17280,'Y','Do Not Pick'),
-- 3-Several containers for the same component, but only the first two should be "picked" (30 + 790) >= 480
 ('1266',2192645,'value Pack - A','10/31/2017','S058',30,480, 'N', 'Pick'),
 ('1266',2192645,'value Pack - A','11/1/2017','S061', 790,480,'Y','Pick'),
 ('1266',2192645,'value Pack - A','11/1/2017','S062',800,480,'Y','Do Not Pick'),
 -- 4-Top container has enough quantity for this component.
 ('1266',2192647,'Value Pack Tray','11/1/2017','S064',1500,980,'Y','Pick'),
 ('1266',2192647,'Value Pack Tray','11/1/2017','S066',1500,980,'Y','Do Not Pick');

SELECT * FROM #CONTAINER
```

[image: results should look like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT
    Job_No
    , Component_Key
    , Component_Name
    , Add_Date
    , Container_No
    , Container_Qty
    , Required_Qty
    , Sufficient_QTY
    , Select_Logic
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Job_No
            , Component_Key
            , Component_Name
            , Add_Date
            , Container_No
            , Container_Qty
            , Required_Qty
            , Sufficient_QTY
            , Select_Logic
            , SUM(CASE WHEN [Sum] >= Required_Qty THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Component_Key, Component_Name ORDER BY R) Pick
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    Job_No
                    , Component_Key
                    , Component_Name
                    , Add_Date
                    , Container_No
                    , Container_Qty
                    , Required_Qty
                    , Sufficient_QTY
                    , Select_Logic
                    , R
                    , SUM(Container_Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY Component_Key, Component_Name ORDER BY R) [Sum]
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            Job_No
                            , Component_Key
                            , Component_Name
                            , Add_Date
                            , Container_No
                            , Container_Qty
                            , Required_Qty
                            , Sufficient_QTY
                            , Select_Logic
                            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Component_Key, Component_Name ORDER BY Add_Date) R
                        FROM #CONTAINER
                    ) Q
            ) Q
    ) Q
WHERE Pick <= 1
ORDER BY
    Component_Key
    , Component_Name
    , Add_Date
```

Comment: Chris, thank you very much for your solution. It works great!!

Answer (score 0):

Your data is strange: `Blister 6 Pack` and `Blister Oral-B` have the same Component_Key, but you treat them as different. That's why Component_Name comes up everywhere as ORDER BY and PARTITION BY.

You need to Pick until the cumulative container_Qty exceeds the Required_Qty. That means Pick as long as the cumultive sum of the **previous** record was insufficient. You get that sum from the cumulative sum minus the current value.

```
SELECT  Job_No,
  Component_Key,
  Component_Name,
  Add_Date,
  Container_No,
  Container_Qty,
  Required_Qty,
  Sufficient_QTY,
  CASE WHEN SUM (Container_Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY Component_Key, Component_Name ORDER BY Add_Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - Container_Qty < Required_Qty THEN 'Pick'
  ELSE 'Do not pick' END AS Select_Logic
FROM CONTAINER
ORDER BY Component_Key, Component_Name, Add_Date
```

Comment: My apologies. The components mentioned  have different component keys. That was a copy/paste mistake. Thank you for the suggestion. I'll test that, and let you know. Appreciate it.

Comment: ItsLex, I'm trying to run your code and getting an error in the CASE statement after Add_Date (ROWS). Thanks

Comment: I tested it on SQLserver 2012 and it runs without error. You should check for typos.

Comment: I'm copying your code, and running as is, and getting the error below: The following errors occurred during execution of the SQL query:

Syntax error in SQL on line 49 symbol 99. Found 'ROWS', expected ';'.

Comment: Line 49? Anyway, ROWS and RANGE are Window Functions which are part of the Analytic functions. New to 2012. Did you try `Select @@version` to make sure you have 2012?

Comment: ItsLex, we are on sql server 2014. Thanks

Comment: And is your comptibility level >= 110? `SELECT name, compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases `